Image clipping through navbar when I change opacity
I am using JavaScript to make the background content of my webpage have reduced opacity when the 'sidebar' appears.
I have div with the class "burger-icon" which is inside the nav.
I have div with the class "sidebar sidebar-hidden", which is a hidden sidebar that appears when you click the burger-icon.
And finally, I have a div with the class "frontimage", which is an image underneath the navbar.
I added position: sticky; to the nav, and now I've noticed that when I hit the burger-icon, the image is appearing on-top of the nav when I open the sidebar. This is happening because my background-color for the nav is white, and with the reduced opacity, the image appears through the nav. Changing the z-index doesn't solve this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?


const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
const burgericon = document.querySelector(".burger-icon");
const closebtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn");
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const frontimage = document.querySelector(".frontimage");

const opensidebar = function() {
  sidebar.classList.remove("sidebar-hidden");
  nav.classList.add("nav-hidden");
  frontimage.classList.add("nav-hidden");
};

const closesidebar = function() {
  sidebar.classList.add("sidebar-hidden");
  nav.classList.remove("nav-hidden");
  frontimage.classList.remove("nav-hidden");
};

burgericon.addEventListener("click", opensidebar);
closebtn.addEventListener("click", closesidebar);
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.burger-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background-color: #1b2225;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.burger-icon span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger-icon span:first-child {
  top: 23px;
}

.burger-icon span:last-child {
  top: 32px;
}

.sidebar {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fa9537;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.nav-hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
<nav>
  <div class="burger-icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</nav>

<div class="sidebar sidebar-hidden">
  <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
</div>

<div class="frontimage">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="frontimage">
  <div class="overlay-text">
  </div>
</div>




It is hard to reproduce your problem. Where are the styles for the burger icon?

I think attaching the actual image, css of the .burger-icon will help you get an answer. Please provide us with a code to reproduce the problems you're experiencing :)

Hi @AntonijaŠimić, I've added the burger-icon styling now!
